# Regex return true if even a substring follows the pattern

Tags: java, regex

I was just practicing regex and found something intriguing

for a string

`"world9 a9$ b6$"` my regular expression `"^(?=.*[\\d])(?=\\S+\\$).{2,}$"`

will return false as there is a space in between before the look ahead finds the $ sign with at least one digit and non space character.

*As a whole the string doesn't matches the pattern.*

**What should be the regular expression if I want to return true even if a substring follows a pattern?**
as in this one a9$ and b6$ both follow the regular expression.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: Replace `(?=\\S+\\$)` with `(?=.*?\\S\\$)`?

Comment: The digit and `$` by them selves are already 2 characters, so you can also directly match it. `^(?=.*\d).*\S\$.*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does return true, can you explain what it is doing?

Comment: Matches a non-whitespace  + `$` anywhere after any 0 or more chars other than line break chars.

Comment: wait, I got it, is it just that now it will look for 0 or more characters with have a nonspace word and $ after wards? Thanks I understood the concept now, what is the need of ? though?? the second one how is .*? doing something different from .*

Comment: It is basically the same. I just assumed the `\S\$` pattern is closer to the start of string. `.*` is used when we assume the next subpatterns appear close the end of string.

Comment: How does this change based on assumption help? Is it more efficient? if yes, how?

Comment: `.*` and `.*?` are the same in efficiency terms when we do not know where matches occur. But if you know that, you may use either `.*` (matches closer to the end) or `.*?` (matches closer to the start).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225328/discussion-between-varun-sharma-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: I think the big thing is you need to use Matcher#find() rather than Matcher#match().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```java
^(?=\D*\d)(?=.*\S\$).{2,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yl4lDc/1/). As [The fourth bird mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076058/regex-return-true-if-even-a-substring-is-follows-the-pattern/65076359#comment115048027_65076058), since `\S\$` matches two chars, you may simply move the pattern to the consuming part, and use `^(?=\D*\d).*\S\$.*$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yl4lDc/2/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit if used in `.matches()`)
- `(?=\D*\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more non-digit chars followed with a digit char immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?=.*\S\$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, followed with a non-whitespace char and a `$` char immediately to the right of the current location
- `.{2,}` - any two or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string (implicit if used in `.matches()`)

Answer (score -1):

Mostly, knock out the `^` and `$` bits, as those force this into a full string match, and you want substring matches. In general, look-ahead seems like a mistake here, what are you trying to accomplish by using that? (Look-ahead/look-behind is rarely needed in general). All you need is:

```
Pattern.compile("\\S+\\$");
```

possibly, if you want an element (such as `a9$`) to stand on its own, use `\b` which is regexpese for word break: Basically, whitespace (and a few other characters, such as underscores. Most non-letter, non-digits characters are considered a break. Think `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`) - but `\b` also matches start/end of input. Thus:

```
Pattern.compile("\\b\\S+\\$\\b")
```

still matches `foo a9$ bar`, or `a9$` just fine.

If you MUST put this in terms of a full match, e.g. because `matches()` (which always does a full string match) is run and you can't change that, well, put `^.*` in front and `.*$` at the back of it, simple as that.

Absolutely nothing about this says "This can only be needed with lookahead".